# On the relative strength of some extensional equality axioms

Tags: coq

Given the following axioms:

```
Definition Axiom1 : Prop := forall (a b:Type) (f g: a -> b),
    (forall x, f x = g x) -> f = g.


Definition Axiom2 : Prop := forall (a:Type) (B:a -> Type) (f g: forall x, B x),
    (forall x, f x = g x) -> f = g.
```

One can easily show that `Axiom2` is a stronger axiom than `Axiom1`:

```
Theorem Axiom2ImpAxiom1 : Axiom2 -> Axiom1.
Proof.
    intros H a b f g H'. apply H. exact H'.
Qed.
```

Does anyone know if (within the type theory of Coq), these two axioms are in fact equivalent or whether they are known not to be. If equivalent, is there a simple Coq proof of the fact?

Comment: Look into *functional extensionality*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the two axioms are equivalent; the key is to go through `fun x => existT B x (f x)` and `fun x => existT B x (g x)`, though there's some tricky equality reasoning that has to be done.  There's a nearly complete proof at https://github.com/HoTT/HoTT/blob/c54a967526bb6293a0802cb2bed32e0b4dbe5cdc/contrib/old/Funext.v#L113-L358 which uses slightly different terminology.

Comment: Thanks very much Jason !